# Jaxb marshaller ang generics(2)

Tags: spring, generics, jaxb, marshalling

there are types:

```
class A{}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"obj"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class B<T extends A> extends A{
  private T obj;

  @XmlElement(required = true)
  public T getObj() {
    return obj;
  }
}
```

When i'm trying to marshal this i get an error:

```
org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingFailureException: JAXB marshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.my.B" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

**Does jaxbMarshaller work with generic?
Any ideas?**

thanks

Answer (score 1):

How is your JAXBContext getting created?  You will need to ensure that it is aware of B.class.  You may need to use the @XmlSeeAlso annotation.

Given the following:

```
public class A {

}
```

and:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"obj"})
@XmlRootElement(name = "response")
public class B<T extends A> extends A {

  private T obj;

  @XmlElement(required = true)  
  public T getObj() {  
    return obj;  
  }

  public void setObj(T obj) {
      this.obj = obj;
  }

}
```

When I run:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(B.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        B b = new B();
        b.setObj(new A());
        marshaller.marshal(b, System.out);

    }

}
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
    <obj/>
</response>
```

And when I run:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(B.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        B b = new B();
        b.setObj(new B());
        marshaller.marshal(b, System.out);

    }

}
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<response>
    <obj xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="b"/>
</response>
```

Comment: i'm trying to marshal instance of the following class:
public class B<C> extends A{
...
}

WHERE C is sub class of A

Comment: I have updated my answer, it may be related to how your JAXBContext is getting created.

Comment: hey Blaise, I couldnt make out what is causing the namespace to occur in the second. I am facing a similar issue where generics are getting printed with namespcae (schema ) infor while concrete classes are just fine, nice xml. Can you pont to me how to go about it? I am using annotation by the way and have tried specifying @XmlSchema at pacjkage and type level but to no success.